# Do I need to call Dispose() on a static object?

Tags: c#, static, dispose

If I have a static WebClient object, do I need to call Dispose() on it at the end of Main()?

Comment: The better solution would be _not_ to have static IDisposables.

Comment: Note; `WebClient` is not thread-safe; if you are using it in a `static` field there is a lot of opportunity for inappropriate usage..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should always `Dispose()` objects when you're finished with them, regardless of where you put the object.

If the object is in a static field, it may be more difficult to figure out when you're finished with it.

Comment: Other than a good rule of thumb, why say always dispose? What specific reason is there to dispose in this particular case? The process will just be ripped out of memory will it not?

Comment: @Kent: We don't know what `WebClient.Dispose` does.

Comment: I checked; it doesn't actually do anything.  In general, however, you should always dispose.

Comment: @Kent Boogaart: The purpose of Dispose isn't to destroy an object; it is to allow an object to clean up outside entities (which might not even be on the same computer!) so that it may be safely abandoned.

Comment: @supercat: in which case, the types in question should include finalizers that will ensure the remote resources are cleaned up. Dispose is just for deterministic clean-up.

Comment: @Kent: It is better to not rely on the finalizer.

Comment: @Kent Boogaart: While there are some occasions when Finalize can be useful, it is not always practical to design classes to behave nicely if abandoned.  The event handler contract, for example, is too weak to allow unknown publishers' events from to be unsubscribed from within Finalize.

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule, you should dispose of any disposable objects. This will allow them to clean up any resources. However, there is no guarantee that dispose will be called on a disposable type - the consumer could neglect to call it, and the CLR does not automatically call it.

If a type *really* needs its clean-up logic to execute (such as when allocating unmanaged memory or creating a heap of files on the file system), it should implement a finalizer in conjunction with the dispose pattern. The CLR will call the finalizer on process exit if it hasn't already been called (typically through disposing the object). Yes, there are some caveats around this (a bad finalizer can spoil the party for other finalizable instances, for example) but the CLR guarantees to at least *try* to run all finalizers on process exit.

So technically, I don't there's any reason why you absolutely must call the dispose method in this case. However, it's a good habit to get into nevertheless.

Comment: Do not assume that `Dispose()` will done done by the OS.  For example, the OS won't delete temp files.

Comment: I didn't assume that. I just don't think WebClient needs it. i.e. the specific case does not call for it. And shouldn't the type include a finalizer if it does depend on its clean-up logic to execute?

Comment: The OS does delete tempoarary files. if the user was smart enough to use the right method to create them ;)

Comment: @Slaks Why won't `Dispose()` be called automatically? It will be called in the object finalizer.

Comment: @Centro: The finalizer is not guaranteed to run.   http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/08/09/10047586.aspx

Comment: @TomTom what's the magic function that guarantees temp file clean up no matter how the process terminates? I ask because I'd like to start using it!

Comment: @David: `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY`, I believe.

Comment: @Slaks _The proof of this is simple: Run the program on a machine with more RAM than the amount of memory required by program._ I always have my finalizers run on a machine with 8 GB RAM. I don't believe that my apps all need more than 8 GB. That sounds as nonsense to me. In all books, articles I've read on garbage collection there is nothing about it.

Comment: @SLaks: calling dispose won't guarantee anything either. What if a purple unicorn gallops past your PC and trips the power cord out then stomps all over your UPS, just prior to dispose being called?

Comment: @Centro: He's not saying that it _will_ not collect anything; he's saying that it _could_ not collect anything.

Comment: @Slaks: Anyway not clear, at least he shouldn't have written _"The proof of this is simple"_ :) Also according to his statement - _"Run the program on a machine with more RAM than the amount of memory required by program. Under these circumstances, the null garbage collector is a valid garbage collector, and the null garbage collector never runs finalizers since it never collects anything."_ - , if I understand it right, the finalizers are never run. In most cases a program is run with enough RAM and he says _"the null garbage collector never runs finalizers since it never collects anything"_.